# cannot connect to BLE peripheral

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-bluetooth, cbcentralmanager

I cannot seem to connect to a BLE peripheral from OSX. I can scan just fine, but connection never happens. I am saving a local copy of the `CBPeripheral*` object - in fact, I can query it and the connection state is `CBPeripheralStateConnecting`, and if I cancel connection it changes back to `CBPeripheralStateDisconnected`. But it never actually connects - the state doesn't change to `CBPeripheralStateConnected` and none of my connect callbacks ever get called.

I can use the LightBlue OSX app to connect, scan services, and read characteristics, so I know my dongle is fine. My code is based on someone else's code, and I know that code worked for him. My code also works fine on iOS, but not on my MacBook. I went ahead and upgraded to El Capitan as well, but that didn't help.

I've tried various things: saving discovered peripheral objects in an array, saving the peripheral I'm connecting to in a property, dispatching the call to `connectPeripheral` to the main thread... no luck. The relevant part of the code is below, and [my entire BLE code is in a gist](https://gist.github.com/kived/0e7d910994ba69e807ff5bb9cf662d68).

```
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _peripherals = [NSMutableArray new];
        _connecting = nil;
        eventlock = [[NSLock alloc] init];
        events = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        central = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self
                                            queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) addPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    if (![self.peripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
        NSLog(@"saving peripheral");
        [self.peripherals addObject:peripheral];
    }
}

- (void) connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    if (![self.peripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
        NSLog(@"error: connect to invalid peripheral");
        return;
    }
    __weak cbcentral *this = self;
    NSLog(@"dispatch connect peripheral");
    self.connecting = peripheral;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"connect peripheral");
        //this.connecting = peripheral;
        [central connectPeripheral:this.connecting
                 options:nil];
    });
}

#pragma mark CBCentralManagerDelegate

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
         didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
         advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
         RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"did discover peripheral");
    [self addPeripheral:peripheral];
    NSArray* event = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"centralManager_didDiscoverPeripheral_advertisementData_RSSI_",
                                                      central,
                                                      peripheral,
                                                      advertisementData,
                                                      RSSI,
                                                      nil];
    [self queueEvent:event];
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
         didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {
    NSLog(@"did connect peripheral");
    [self addPeripheral:peripheral];
    NSArray* event = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"centralManager_didConnectPeripheral_",
                                                      central,
                                                      peripheral,
                                                      nil];
    [self queueEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to create an array of UUIDs for services at first?

Comment: @ElTomato For scanning? It's not necessary; doing so just filters the peripherals. I'm able to scan and find my peripheral, but when I try to connect (`connectPeripheral:` method) it just never gets out of the connecting state.

Comment: Okay.  Interestingly, I've tried the same thing yesterday and had pretty much the same issue.  I've resorted Introduction to Core Bluetooth: Building a Heart Rate Monitor, and their project doesn't seem to connect the device, either.